# How to get simple face detection working?

Tags: firebase, tensorflow-lite, firebase-mlkit

I am trying to get a simple example of face detection working with ML Kit on iOS. Here is excerpts of the Objective C code:

```
    FIRVisionFaceDetectorOptions *faceDetectorOptions;
    FIRVision *vision;
    FIRVisionFaceDetector *faceDetector;

    faceDetectorOptions = [[FIRVisionFaceDetectorOptions alloc] init];
    faceDetectorOptions.performanceMode = FIRVisionFaceDetectorPerformanceModeAccurate;
    faceDetectorOptions.landmarkMode = FIRVisionFaceDetectorLandmarkModeAll;
    faceDetectorOptions.contourMode = FIRVisionFaceDetectorContourModeNone;
    faceDetectorOptions.classificationMode = FIRVisionFaceDetectorClassificationModeAll;
    faceDetectorOptions.minFaceSize = 0.1; // TODO: finalize this option value

    vision = [FIRVision vision];
    faceDetector = [vision faceDetectorWithOptions:faceDetectorOptions];

    UIImage *staticImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sample.jpg"];
    FIRVisionImage *visionImage = [[FIRVisionImage alloc] initWithImage:staticImg];

    NSError* error = Nil;
    NSArray<FIRVisionFace *> * faces = [faceDetector resultsInImage:visionImage error:&error];
    NSLog(@"Synchronous result. error = %@, face count = %lu", error, faces.count);
```

The `sample.jpg` file is the following image downloaded and added as a resource to my Xcode project:
http://chwb.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Theo_Janssen-Face1.jpg

The `resultsInImage` returns no error, but no faces either. It logs:

```
Synchronous result. error = (null), face count = 0
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The problem was I need to set the image metadata with orientation like this:

```
    FIRVisionImageMetadata *imageMetadata = [FIRVisionImageMetadata new];
    imageMetadata.orientation = [FcFaceDetector visionImageOrientationFromImageOrientation:uiImage.imageOrientation];
    visionImage.metadata = imageMetadata;
```

```
+ (FIRVisionDetectorImageOrientation) visionImageOrientationFromImageOrientation:(UIImageOrientation)imageOrientation {
    switch (imageOrientation) {
            case UIImageOrientationUp:
            return FIRVisionDetectorImageOrientationTopLeft;
            case UIImageOrientationDown:
            return FIRVisionDetectorImageOrientationBottomRight;
            case UIImageOrientationLeft:
            return FIRVisionDetectorImageOrientationLeftBottom;
            case UIImageOrientationRight:
            return FIRVisionDetectorImageOrientationRightTop;
            case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:
            return FIRVisionDetectorImageOrientationTopRight;
            case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
            return FIRVisionDetectorImageOrientationBottomLeft;
            case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
            return FIRVisionDetectorImageOrientationLeftTop;
            case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
            return FIRVisionDetectorImageOrientationRightBottom;
    }
}
```

The docs seem to be unclear about it, because it seems to suggest to not set it:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/ios/detect-faces#2-run-the-face-detector